# How to write a code in R to sort the values of a column for the similar row values?

Tags: r

As you see, I have two columns (stop_id and arrival time). I have to write a code (maybe a for-loop), that sorts the values of `arrival_time` for the same `stop_id`. For example, as you see, for the `stop_id = 12893`, I have three `arrival_time` values, which are not in the ascending order. These are:

```
5:49:49;
20:34:07; and
18:51:13
```

I cannot do it manually, cause I have about 11,000 unique `stop_id values`. Thanks in advance.

```
stop_id arrival_time
12893   5:19:49
12893   6:20:31
12893   6:50:31
12893   7:20:31
12893   7:50:31
12893   8:20:31
12893   8:50:31
12893   9:04:49
12893   10:04:49
12893   11:04:49
12893   12:04:49
12893   5:49:49
12893   13:04:49
12893   14:04:49
12893   15:21:13
12893   15:51:13
12893   16:21:13
12893   16:51:13
12893   17:21:13
12893   17:51:13
12893   18:21:13
12893   19:19:07
12893   19:49:07
12893   21:34:07
12893   22:34:07
12893   23:34:07
12893   24:45:07
12893   20:34:07
12893   18:51:13
12898   5:51:56
12898   6:22:30
12898   7:22:30
12898   7:52:30
12898   8:22:30
12898   8:52:30
12898   10:52:56
12898   11:52:56
12898   12:52:56
12898   13:52:56
12898   6:52:30
12898   9:52:56
12898   5:21:56
12898   14:52:56
12898   15:57:30
12898   16:27:30
12898   16:57:30
12898   17:27:30
12898   17:57:30
12898   18:27:30
12898   18:57:30
12898   20:22:22
12898   21:22:22
12898   22:22:22
12898   23:22:22
12898   24:22:22
12898   19:22:22
12898   15:27:30
```

Comment: To get started, check out the `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages. They are very popular R packages and will help you get your times in a time format rather than text, which will be crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `dplyr`.
For example:

`dplyr::arrange(dataframe, stop_id, arrival_time)`

Comment: This will sort the arrival times alphabetically, e.g., putting `10:00:00` before `2:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say you should convert your `arrival_time` column to an appropriate class that knows about time, like the `times` class from the `chron` package. Unfortunately, your times aren't normal, because you have some beyond `23:59:59`, so the standard `times` class won't work.

Instead, we'll split the column into hours, minutes, and seconds, and sort on those:

```
library(tidyr)
res = separate(df, col = arrival_time, into = c("h", "m", "s"), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)
res = with(res, res[order(stop_id, h, m, s), ])
res
#    stop_id arrival_time  h  m  s
# 1    12893      5:19:49  5 19 49
# 12   12893      5:49:49  5 49 49
# 2    12893      6:20:31  6 20 31
# 3    12893      6:50:31  6 50 31
# 4    12893      7:20:31  7 20 31
# 5    12893      7:50:31  7 50 31
# 6    12893      8:20:31  8 20 31
# 7    12893      8:50:31  8 50 31
# 8    12893      9:04:49  9  4 49
# 9    12893     10:04:49 10  4 49
# 10   12893     11:04:49 11  4 49
# 11   12893     12:04:49 12  4 49
# 13   12893     13:04:49 13  4 49
# ...
```